# Why curl not working when I post some values?

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to post some values to a URL using curl

```
//set up a connection variable for the page you will post data to
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://payment.teqwerty.com/NetBanking/Pay.jsp?');
 
//curl basic setup
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 
//$_POST variables to pass
$post_items[] = 'MerchantId='.strip_tags($merchantId);
$post_items[] = 'Password='.strip_tags($Password);
$post_items[] = 'RemoteIP='.strip_tags($RemoteIP);
$post_items[] = 'Amount='.strip_tags($Amount);
$post_items[] = 'BankId='.strip_tags($BankId);
$post_items[] = 'Checksum='.strip_tags($checksum);
$post_items[] = 'Name='.strip_tags($Name);
$post_items[] = 'mobileNo='.strip_tags($mobileNo);
$post_items[] = 'Email='.strip_tags($Email);

 
//format the $post_items into a string
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
 
//send the $_POST data to the new page
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

I'm new to curl, this code, I got searching from google. But it doesn't seems to be working. But I have a working code

```
$parameters='MerchantId='.$merchantId.'&Password='.$Password.'&ReferenceNo='.$ReferenceNo.'&RemoteIP='.$RemoteIP.'&Amount='.$Amount.'&BankId='.$BankId.'&Checksum='.$checksum.'&Name='.$Name.'&MobileNo='.$MobileNo.'&Email='.$Email;
    //echo "para is <br>".$parameters;
    //set POST variables
    $url = 'https://payment.teqwerty.com/NetBanking/Pay.jsp?'.$parameters; 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $auth = curl_exec($curl);
```

The above works fine. But weirdly sometimes this will get stuck and don't work. I want to post the parameters to that URL. I will not get any variables in return anyway. Why does the first code not working. Am I doing it in the wrong way?

Comment: try post url "https://payment.teqwerty.com/NetBanking/Pay.jsp" then $postfields and curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST,1);

Comment: When the second method is working why not use it ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It is working,but sometimes it getting stuck.I cant figure out the reason for that.Sometimes it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This answer is with respect to the below comment..

> @ShankarDamodaran.. It is working,but sometimes it getting stuck.I
>   cant figure out the reason for that.Sometimes it works fine

Then it must be definitely the url encoding issue.

Do like this..

```
$parameters='MerchantId='.$merchantId.'&Password='.$Password.'&ReferenceNo='.$ReferenceNo.'&RemoteIP='.$RemoteIP.'&Amount='.$Amount.'&BankId='.$BankId.'&Checksum='.$checksum.'&Name='.$Name.'&MobileNo='.$MobileNo.'&Email='.$Email
$parameters = urlencode($parameters); //<--- URL Encode it before sending to the cURL
```

Comment: Ok will check it and will let you know

Comment: Encoding it doesnt work.It gives me error at the api side,since what im posting is not in the right format.The current one is now working.But cant trust it,coz it sometimes dont.any other possiblity of why is it getting stuck some times?

Comment: Actually there was a typo on my code... I missed a `e` in the `$parameters` variable. What do you actually mean by `stuck` ? Can you explain ?

Comment: I have removed the typo,the error doesn't come now.I will explain,there is a form which collects all the details(params) to be sent to the url.Its actually  a payment  form.User fills it,and click on pay.Then he taken to this php as the form action.The values he filled in the form wil be saved into the variables and using curl,will be posted to the above url,through curl.Actually its working fine,but i hv found tht some of my clients have issues,after filing form,when they click pay,the php doesnt load,its blank(instead of taking them to 3D secure page,that what it should do after curl post)

Answer (score 0):

As, you prevent the SSL verify to false. curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
Then, i guess you also have to mention the SSL version i.e curl_setopt($init_curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

This is just a thought. Because i was also previously facing such kind of issue. Then, i mentioned the SSL version and it worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one way of sending http data POST or GET. First approach uses POST while second approach uses GET. And as you say, that first approach not working, So it is clear that your request must be sent only through as GET request.

For problem of sometimes not working, You must check response header/data to get more information.

For only check headers use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
```